# connect twilio to ip phone

Tags: voip, twilio, pbx

I am finding information that is very confusing on this issue.

What is best way to connect a sip phone ( ie yealink t22 ) to a twilio account. Do I need a PBX with sip trunk or can it be done directly?

Lots of dated info online.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly connect the device to Twilio, as they do not support device registration. So as it would work, is that you would need to connect your device to some or other sip registration server. There is an example that I know of using FreeSwitch, perhaps you can get a few ideas from it.
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/trying-out-the-twilio-sip-noun-using-freeswitch.html